# Division of prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

a)
Let p and q be different odd primes. Is there any such numbers for which $$(p-1)(q-1) \mid (pq)^2 +3$$?

b)
Let q be an odd prime number. Is there any q for which $$6(q-1) \mid 81q^2 + 3$$?

(I expect the answer for both to be no) 
(q does not equal 3)

These are small chunks from a number theory problem that  left me to solve and I'll be done with the problem. Can someone please help? The original problem is from a regional Bulgarian competition.

Comment: I consulted with my teacher and he confirmed that the given solution involve the solving of these two and because of this I found it unnecessary.

Comment: Ok ,thanks for that.

Comment: I'm sorry again all primes can't be 3

Answer (score 2):

b) requires $q-1|81q^2+3= 81(q-1+1)^2+3=\lambda (q-1)+84$, so $q-1|84$
And since q is odd and $81q^2+3=4(\mod 8)$, $q-1=2(\mod 4)$
so $q-1 \in \{2, 6, 14, 42\}$, or $q \in \{3,7,43\}$
We could verify only 3 is valid.

Answer (score 1):

$p=3$,$q=7$ for $a$ and $q=3$ for $b$)
since $(3-1)(7-1)=12$ which divides $(3·7)^2+3=444$
and $6(3-1)=12|(81·3^2)+3=732$

Comment: Look at the edit :)

Answer (score 0):

If both p and q are larger than 3, it is obvious that both p-1 and q-1 is not multiple of 3.

And since $(pq)^2+3=4(\mod 8)$, both $m=\frac{p-1}2$ and $n=\frac{q-1}2$ are odd number.

Since $m| p^2q^2+3$, -3 is [quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) of m so that $m=1(\mod 6)$ which means $p=3(\mod 6)$ and it is invalid since p should be prime more than 3.

Comment: Excuse me if I dint understand but how p is larger than p. Also if q is 7 q-1 is multiple of 3

Comment: If q-1 is multiple of 3, then (p-1)(q-1) is multiple of 3 but $p^2q^2+3$ is not multiple of 3 which is contradict to $(p-1)(q-1)|p^2q^2+3$

Comment: It should be if both p and q are larger than 3. I have modified it now.

Comment: Can you explain why m can't equal 5 (mod 6) please. I figured why it can't be 3, but I can't understand the quadratic residue thing. I will be grateful if their is other way.

Comment: $-3=(pq)^2 (mod m)$ means -3 is quadratic residue of m by definition.

Using the Law of quadratic reciprocity in the wiki page, we could find out that m can't equal $5(\mod 6)$. Or we could use the table in the wiki which shows that  if -3 is quadratic residue of m, $m = 1 (\mod 3)$

Comment: I'm really sorry if I'm starting to be annoying but is any chance that there is other proof you can suggest which does not used the quadratic residue.

Comment: And also how do you prove 3*7 is the only one with 3

Comment: If p=3, the condition becomes $2(q-1)|9q^2+3=9(q-1+1)^2+3=r (q-1)+12$
so we must have $q-1|12$. So q=3,5,7,13. And we could verify that only q=3 or q=7 works